# Solidity - Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I can run the set function with values with `instance.SetUserInfo('Neil', 43)` and I get a confirmation that it's a success, when I try to get function with `instance.GetUserInfo('Neil')`
My command line commands are as follows:

```
let instance = await test.deployed()
instance.SetUserInfo('Neil', 43)
instance.GetUserInfo('Neil')
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:18
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:49
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:273:12)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:140:14)
    at runScript (C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:366:1)
    at Console.interpret (C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:381:1)
    at bound (domain.js:416:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:427:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:819:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:342:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:671:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1015:14) {
  hijackedStack: "Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.\n" +
    '    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth-abi\\lib\\index.js:297:1)\n' +
    '    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth-abi\\lib\\index.js:284:1)\n' +
    '    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth\\node_modules\\web3-eth-contract\\lib\\index.js:469:1)\n' +
    '    at Method.outputFormatter (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth\\node_modules\\web3-eth-contract\\lib\\index.js:759:1)\n' +
    '    at Method.formatOutput (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\lib\\index.js:146:1)\n' +
    '    at sendTxCallback (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-eth\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\lib\\index.js:522:1)\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3\\node_modules\\web3-core-requestmanager\\lib\\index.js:307:1\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\provider\\wrapper.js:119:1\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3\\node_modules\\web3-providers-http\\lib\\index.js:98:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:208:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:318:1)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:289:48)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:532:15)\n' +
    '    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)'
}
```

My .sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract test {

   struct UserInfo {
        uint Age;
        bool AgeRestriction;
    }

    mapping (string => UserInfo) AllUsers;

    function SetUserInfo(string memory  _Name, uint _Age) public {
        AllUsers[_Name].Age = _Age;
        if (AllUsers[_Name].Age >= 18)  {AllUsers[_Name].AgeRestriction = false;
       }
       else AllUsers[_Name].AgeRestriction = true;
}
       function GetUserInfo(string memory _Name) public view returns (uint) {
      
        return (AllUsers[_Name].Age);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue - works fine when I try to execute the setter and getter in Remix. Please edit the question and show steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PetrHejda thats the part im confused about, I am running this in visual studio code with truffle commands, so what I am assuming in that case is that contract address needs to be restated on the getter - the above code is exactly what I am executing

Comment: Ok can you share the JS code and exact commands (including their arguments, flags, and options if you're using any) in an edit to your question?

Comment: @PetrHejda thanks for your patience, just uploaded whatever else I can

Comment: Can you share the full JS code? The ABI JSON seems correct, so you can remove it to save space in the question... Wild guess based on the `test` variable name - your script redeploys the contract before each test case and accesses non-existing instance in the second test case.

Comment: @PetrHejda sorry if im sounding confusing, but im not running JS code to run it , I am using truffle command line in Visual Studio - the only other JS code is the migration file which is irrelevant I assume.

Comment: @PetrHejda " your script redeploys the contract before each test case and accesses non-existing instance in the second test case" - that sounds about right, but should I not be addressing that instance by way of a contract address?

Comment: So unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in truffle console either, and I'm out of ideas right now. https://imgur.com/zXvpvm6

Comment: @PetrHejda see my solution below, absolutely mind blown - after pulling what little hair out that I have

Answer (score 1):

Well I will be damned, for whatever reason this worked.

instead of using:

```
truffle develop
```

I used

```
truffle console
```

and it worked

Hope someone finds this useful